# How to get details of table topic wise in Xcode?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have done a simple Contact app which helps user to create a contact with email and phone number. Now I am trying to add about 100 contacts from a table. So I need to be able to read the title of each column and get the data accordingly from the text file and feed it to my function in the xcode. These are the heading of my contacts table in my file, contacts.txt:

```
Emp_ID   Name   Email   Contact_Number
```

What are the different ways to achieve this?

I have a table with these headings saved in a text file, contacts.txt. No, database and SQL.

This is a sample of how my Contacts.txt file looks like in xcode

```
\itap1\trowd \taflags1 \trgaph108\trleft-108 \trcbpat3 \tamart320 \tamarb320 \trmarr320 \trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth360\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx1728
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth1580\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx3456
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth3180\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx5184
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth6020\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx6912
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth3200\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx8640
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480

\f0\b\fs32 \cf0 #
\b0 \cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480

\b \cf0 Emp_ID
\b0 \cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480

\b \cf0 Name
\b0 \cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480

\b \cf0 Email
\b0 \cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480

\b \cf0 Contact_Number
\b0 \cell \row

\itap1\trowd \taflags1 \trgaph108\trleft-108 \trcbpat3 \tamart320 \tamarb320 \trmarr320 \trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth360\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx1728
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth1580\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx3456
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth3180\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx5184
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth6020\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx6912
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth3200\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx8640
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 1\cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 Emp1000\cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 Name1\cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 name1@gmail.com\cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 9874563210\cell \row

\itap1\trowd \taflags1 \trgaph108\trleft-108 \trcbpat3 \tamart320 \tamarb320 \trmarr320 \trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth360\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx1728
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth1580\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx3456
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth3180\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx5184
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth6020\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx6912
\clvertalc \clshdrawnil \clwWidth3200\clftsWidth3 \clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw20\brdrcf2 \clpadt60 \clpadl60 \clpadb60 \clpadr60 \gaph\cellx8640
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 2\cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 Emp1010\cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 Name2\cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 name2@gmail.com\cell 
\pard\intbl\itap1\pardeftab720\sl480
\cf0 9875463210\cell \row
```

And so on the list continues for name 3 - 100

## Expected output

Array={(Emp1000,Name1,name1@gmail.com,9874563210),(Emp1010,Name2,name2@gmail.com,9875463210)}

This is a code which through which I can get data between any two strings

```
-(NSString*)inString:(NSString*)getStringBetweenString1:(NSString*)sub1 String2:(NSString*)sub2 {
     NSLog(@"%@",start);
    NSRange startRange = [orgstr rangeOfString:start];
    if (startRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSRange targetRange;
        targetRange.location = startRange.location + startRange.length;
        targetRange.length = [orgstr length] - targetRange.location;   
        NSRange endRange = [orgstr rangeOfString:end options:0 range:targetRange];
        if (endRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            targetRange.length = endRange.location - targetRange.location;
            return [orgstr substringWithRange:targetRange];
        }
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: can you give more information? Is your contacts data in sql table or a text file?

Comment: what kind of table ? you mean a text file only ?

Comment: Create an array of contact, and to load first 100 contact make a loop till 100
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
//code to get information from you contact array
}

Comment: @iphonemaclover how will I tell my function in xcode to loop through table in xcode, thats the question. Its a table of 4 columns and 100 rows, I want to know how I can get the data from the table corresponding to each title. For eg if 1st row contain, emp001, firstLastName, name@gmail.com, 9876543210. There's a function in my xcode which have variables, empID, Name, email,PhNo. And email and phNo are array as they can contain multiple value, but thats all right, for time being I jst want to know how do I populate my variables in xcode from table as empID=emp001, Name=firstLastName and so on

Comment: first clear me you are using local database or get it from response from server? as if you are getting it from server then you can easily parse it using some key values, and get all the information easily

Comment: check out similiar solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005183/data-from-txt-file-to-nsarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by modifying the above function which will also return a index.

```
-(NSArray*)inString:(NSString*)main getStringBetweenString1:(NSString*)sub1 string2:(NSString*)sub2 fromIndex:(long int)indexrange
{
    NSMutableArray *returnArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithCapacity:2];
    [returnArray insertObject:@"" atIndex:0];
    [returnArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:NSNotFound] atIndex:1];
    NSString *returnString=@"";
    long int start,end;
    start=[self inString:main getIndexOfSubString:sub1 fromIndex:indexrange];
    if(start==NSNotFound)
        return returnArray;
    end=[self inString:main getIndexOfSubString:sub2 fromIndex:start];
     NSLog(@"Start:%ld end:%ld",start,end);
    if(end==NSNotFound)
        return returnArray;

    for(long int i=start+[sub1 length];i<end;i++)
    {
        returnString=[returnString stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c",[main characterAtIndex:i]]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
    [returnArray insertObject:returnString atIndex:0];
    [returnArray insertObject:[NSNumber numberWithLong:end] atIndex:1];

    return returnArray;
}


-(long int)inString:(NSString*)s getIndexOfSubString:(NSString*)s1 fromIndex:(long int)fromIndex
{
    for(int i=fromIndex;i<[s length];i++)
    {
        if([s characterAtIndex:i]==[s1 characterAtIndex:0])
        {
            int j=i+1,k=1;
            for(k=1;k<[s1 length];k++,j++)
            {
                if([s characterAtIndex:j]!=[s1 characterAtIndex:k])
                    break;
            }
            if(k==[s1 length])
                return i;
        }
    }
    return NSNotFound;
}

-(void)getContactsFromFile:(NSString*)fileName
{
    NSString* path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName
                                                     ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString* content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path
                                                  encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];


 for(long int j=3227;;) //3227 is index at which it should start
    {
        NSArray *cellobj=[self inString:content getStringBetweenString1:@"\\cf0" string2:@"\\cell" fromIndex:j];
        j=[[cellobj objectAtIndex:1] integerValue];
           if(j==NSNotFound)
            break;
         NSLog(@"String:%@",[cellobj objectAtIndex:0]); // prints all details of table topics individually

        NSString *test=[cellobj objectAtIndex:0];
}

//Do something with test
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NSScanner` to parse through your file extracting each column and saving each piece of info into a new contact object. You would use a `while` loop to iterate over each line and create new objects when the scanner has completed all columns for the current line.

See [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/Scanners.html) for guidance on using `NSScanner`.